# What strategy, algorithm, and format should I use to create an articles website?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

Note: I don't want to use open source CMS, and want to write my own here. This is a Designing Question

I want to make a site with articles that offered, something like `DeveloperFusion.com` 's Articles section
Some Info

database: SQL Server

Unicode: yes

Pictures: Yes

Styles: yes

Steps & Issues

1. After inserting a new article via a web editor, How to store the new item e.g: add that as a new record in the articles table in a HTML formatted version with using Server.HtmlEncode method
2. In this way, what should be the data format NCLOB - Text - NVarChar(Max) or ...
3. I don't know is this a common pattern or silly one, but instead of passing it to a database make a webpage with the name of the desired page and add the article-contents to it
4. the way that the client can reach the address e.g `example.com/articles/6643/` if the storage option be SQL how can we pass the code of this article & show that as a webpage

this question isn't for getting code, is specially for knowing the strategy, algorithm and format

Comment: I don't even think this is a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Writing a web application.

*(Seriously, how broad is this question?)*

Comment: LOL! A vague question **should** get a vague answer.

Comment: @annakata ,
I wrote a new version , hope it makes the question clear , thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well First of all you have to design your Database. Make a table for article which should have columns like article_ID, article_Title, article_Content, article_Author etc. In this way you can have each information and take varchar(Max) datatypes for all except id (which would be integer).For storing the new item (article), you have to add each components of your article like articles title, its content and its author separately and this can be done in a single SQL query.Please take some basic ADO.NET tutorials for this.

Don't be confused about html formatted version storage option. Just [Take a look at this web editor](http://ckeditor.com/download). It can be integrated on your web page just like a control. Just download **CKEditor for ASP.NET** and you can use its **Text** property to get article content and just save it on your database and will take care of your formatting. You have to read its document for integration.

For your 3rd question, just make an asp.net webpage for articles and put **ListView** control on it, bind this control to your article database. You can modify this control according to your needs, insert **HyperLink** control to this control that will represent your articles title and will be linked to other page (say ReadPage), set an event for **ListView** control which is called **SelectedIndexChanged**  in which **ListView** will give the primary key of an article table (which would be article ID) and you can save it to any integer variable. Set click event for **HyperLink** control which will navigate to other page(say ReadPage) but before navigation just add the querystring inside the URL ( inside this query string would be an article ID), this hyperlink will navigate to the ReadPage with a query strings. This ReadPage will read the query string and fetch that particular article from data base.

If you have any problem you can search these terms on net.

Hope this answer will help you...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need a CMS solution, Why not try existing open source CMS solutions like Dotnet Nuke or Umbraco?

Chances are that, they have the features (and much more) you are looking for.

Comment: thanks my friend for participating , I wanted to write one from scratch
and some part of it is finished , I wanted to know more about idea ,
a cms that I had looked inside code was very lengthy & complicated to look , but yesterday finally I found my answers

Answer (score 1):

Well i also asked question to display articles which are saved on sql database and it was also stated as vague. I am also making a article reading website.

Well your answer for the 2a would be varchar(max) as it can store up to 2GB
And i am storing article without making a webpage

Comment: Good to know, When you reach a point let me know also, my question a bout data-type was a bit related to past, but what I'm eager still is different strategies to store articles in some structures into databases and not making static web pages.

Answer (score 0):

As annakata stated your question is very broad in scope. It appears from the tags you've specified that your after some kind of cms solution. Maybe have a look at this question for a selection of open source options which may fit your needs:

[Which CMS to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490899/which-cms-to-chose)